# Difficulty in creating Table Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I don't know what is the problem in below code.But I know where the problem arises.It is from the method `createTL()`..It stops unfortunately.Help me to solve this problem.I want to create n rows and 4 columns of `EditText` view.
Edit:Now i initialized both et and tr..but error still arises..Tis is the updated code

```
 public TableLayout createTL(int r)
 {
    int c=4;
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myTL=new TableLayout(Ybus_Activity.this);
myTL.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myTL.setStretchAllColumns(true);
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[r];
    EditText[][] et = new EditText[r][c];
    Arrays.fill(et,"0.0");
    Arrays.fill(tr,et);
for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
          {
            et[i][j].setLayoutParams(params);
            et[i][j].setWidth(100);
            et[i][j].setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            et[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            et[i][j].setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
            et[i][j].setMaxLines(1);
            tr[i].addView(et[i][j]);
            myTL.addView(tr[i]);
            }
    }
//I already have LinearLayout named "main" under onCreate() method...
//main.addView(myTL);
return myTL;
```

}

My Logcat:(updated)

```
02-22 23:15:01.315: D/AndroidRuntime(6445): Shutting down VM
02-22 23:15:01.315: W/dalvikvm(6445): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2e26288)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String cannot be stored in an array of type android.widget.EditText[][]
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:966)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at com.gkn.powersystemcalc.Ybus_Activity.createTL(Ybus_Activity.java:156)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at com.gkn.powersystemcalc.Ybus_Activity$2.onClick(Ybus_Activity.java:140)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-22 23:15:01.345: E/AndroidRuntime(6445):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 23:15:01.385: W/ActivityManager(1026):   Force finishing activity com.gkn.powersystemcalc/.Ybus_Activity
02-22 23:15:01.545: D/dalvikvm(1026): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 899K, 11% free 15374K/17159K, paused 84ms, total 86ms
02-22 23:15:02.074: W/ActivityManager(1026): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b3ac8e38 com.gkn.powersystemcalc/.Ybus_Activity}
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace for god's sacke!

Comment: what is stack trace and where can i find that??

Comment: post your logcat. available into DDMS

Comment: @MD I posted my logcat

Comment: Something is null on line 159 within Ybus_Activity. Which line is 159?

Comment: replace this `myTL=new TableLayout(this);` with `myTL=new TableLayout(youtractivity.this);` and try

Comment: @Jakar : et[i][j].setLayoutParams(params);

This is line no. 159

Comment: @gkn06 I thought so. See my answer.

Comment: @MD its not working..again app stopping unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You are initiating an array of `EditText` at `EditText[][] et = new EditText[r][c];` but that array is filled with `null` objects. You then call methods on those `null` objects which is why you're getting the `NullPointerException`.

You need to fill `et` with initialized `EditText` objects before calling any methods on them.

The same goes for the `TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[r];`

**Edit:** As a note, you may want to change your return type to `TableLayout` or add the `myTL` object to a view that's showing on the screen.

Comment: To fill the arrays easily, you could probably use `Arrays.fill()`

Comment: I think it's something more like `Arrays.fill(et,new EditText(context));`. I'm not exactly sure, though. I haven't used it before. It also my create an additional difficulty since it's a multi-dimensional array. You could maybe do a google search about how to use Arrays.fill

Comment: bro one more doubt...is it possible to initialize tr(tablerow), since it does not holds data..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48155/discussion-between-jakar-and-gkn06)